# Simplifying Water Areas in QGIS for Artwork

Tags: qgis, simplify

I am using QGIS to create geographic artwork with topo and water features.

I have downloaded the NHDWaterbody dataset from the USGS. Some of the wetlands are causing me real issues. For example, here there are tens or maybe hundreds of tiny little areas that are essentially adjacent.

[image]

I am trying to make artwork where this shape is cut out of material and the machine can't capture nearly this much detail. I am looking for a method where I can, as much as possible, combine all these very close shapes into a single large shape. Some loss of detail and precision is perfectly acceptable.

As is, it will try to trace out these hundreds of basically overlapping lines which will cause significant issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ["Dissolve"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#dissolve) tool in `Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Dissolve` to merge all of the features into one.

You could also use the ["Select by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) attribute table tool to select and then remove all the adjacent wetland areas. You would need to find a unique identifier in the attribute table for the classes you do and don't want. For example, given you have a column in the attribute table called 'class' and it is filled with 1s (water) and 0s (wetland), you could do:

```
'class' = 2
```

to select all wetland attributes and then use the delete attributes icon to remove them.